# What is the best way to implement novelty detection using Scikit-learn when I have unpolluted training data (outlier-free)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, anomaly-detection

I have a labeled database with a separate class "-1" in which all the outliers are.

I am currently using sklearn's `LocalOutlierFactor` and `OneClassSVM` for fitting them on outlier-free training data and after that, test them on test data containing outliers. My objective is to check if new unseen examples are outliers before classifying them using a classification model.

It appears that since the training data which I use to fit the models is free of outliers and since the examples in each class are very similar, I get the best results (precision and recall) on the test data if I set the hyperparameter `contamination` of the `LocalOutlierFactor` as low as possible, something like `10**-100`. The higher I set this value the more false outliers my model detects on new data.
I observe a similar behaviour using `OneClassSVM`. The hyperparameters `gamma` and `nu` have to be extremely low that the model serves me the best results.

According to Scikit-learn the training data shall not be polluted by outliers to perform novelty detection. This is explained at the top [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html).

Given this, my question is if I am missing something or if my approach is legit. I don't get why I even have to set the `contamination` hyperparameter if the training data shall not be polluted. It is perfectly clean in my case and `contamination` can't be set to 0 and it seems weird to set it manually to such a low value.

Comment: If you have labeled outliers available, why are you training without them?

Comment: If you have enough labels to make a decent validation set, then do a hyperparameter search using cross-validation, where the contamination factor is one of the hyperparameter. Choose the best performing model